# How to stop async TcpListener properly?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I've two `Button` on my window hooked up to two `ICommands`:

```
public ICommand Start { get; set; }
public ICommand Stop { get; set; }
```

which are initialized in the `Constructor` like this:

```
Start = new Command(StartServer, (o) => !IsListening);
Stop = new Command(StopServer, (o) => IsListening);
```

and do these:

```
async void StartServer(object obj)
{
    server.Start();
    IsListening = true;
    Status = "Listening";
    try
    {
        while (IsListening)
        {
            var cw = new ClientWrapper();
            cw.Client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            cw.EndPoint = cw.Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Pool.Add(cw);
            HandleClient(cw);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}


void StopServer(object obj)
{
    DisposeClients();
    server.Stop();
    IsListening = false;
    Status = "Start Server";
}
```

When I click `Start` it starts listening and accepts clients without any issue. Without any clients, if I just `Start` the server and then click `Stop`, it executes `StopServer` function normally and then hits `ICommand`'s `Execute` function and comes to `catch` block of `StartServer` method! and the message in `e` is:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.

I don't want it to go to `catch` block! How to handle it properly?

Comment: "I don't want it to go to `catch` block!" - a `catch` block *at the server level* is of no consequence whatsoever; frankly, sockets are messy and brittle **by design**: exception handling is normal and expected. "How to handle it properly?" - by not calling `throw` inside the `catch` :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, since `StopServer` executes normally, there's no problem with my `TcpListener` for sure. So the exceptions is thrown from this `await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` line! Now, how can I stop server from `AcceptTcpClientAsync` before stopping. If it's not possible to restrain it from `AcceptTcpClientAsync`, provide a small example in answer section if you don't mind.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an overload that accepts a CancellationToken. So your best bet is to follow Marc's advice and use a try/catch around `await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync()`. Which I would recommend anyway. Depending on the ErrorCode, you can decide if you can actually handle the error or just quit the loop.

Comment: @Fildor, when I tried beginaccept/endaccept type of aynchronous operation a few years ago, I think I used socketerror there. Is there any option to use that with these async/await?

Comment: Sure. SocketException has the [SocketErrorCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketexception.socketerrorcode?view=netframework-4.8) Property.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace tcplistenertest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread listenerThread = StartBackgroundThread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

            while(Console.ReadLine() != string.Empty)
            {
            }

            mListener.Stop();
            listenerThread.Join();
        }

        static void ThreadProc()
        {
            try
            {
                mListener = StartListening();

                AcceptLoop(mListener);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ThreadProc error: {e.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Stack trace:{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
            }
        }

        static Thread StartBackgroundThread(ThreadStart task)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            return thread;
        }

        static TcpListener StartListening()
        {
            TcpListener result = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, PORT);
            result.Start();

            return result;
        }

        static void AcceptLoop(TcpListener listener)
        {
            // this is the main loop of the Socket based server
            while (true)
            {
                Socket socket = null;
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Accepting connection...");
                    socket = AcceptConnection(listener);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Connection accepted from {socket.RemoteEndPoint}");
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Socket error accepting connection: {e.Message}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Stack trace:{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Generic error accepting connection: {e.Message}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Stack trace:{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
                    break;
                }

                try
                {
                    socket.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error closing socket: {e.Message}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Stack trace:{Environment.NewLine}{e.StackTrace}");
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Accept loop thread stopping");
        }

        static Socket AcceptConnection(TcpListener listener)
        {
            Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
            try
            {
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.Debug, 1);
                LingerOption optionValue = new LingerOption(true, 3);

                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                    SocketOptionName.Linger, optionValue);

                return socket;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                socket.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }

        static TcpListener mListener;
        const int PORT = 55000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, add some comment to explain.

Comment: OP is already using async/await. I don't see a benefit from changing all the code to plain old Thread.